# What distribution should be used in an experiment where the sample is smaller at each interval and the observations are dependent?

Tags: r, biostatistics

I did an experiment where I monitored phenology of a specified number of plants (multinomial ranking) and as weeks went by, I used some of the plants for experiments and removed them from the plants being monitored weekly. So sample size was decreasing every week. What distribution should be used in R to model the probabilities of phenological stages taking into account that I am decreasing the samples size on every observation. Note that also the observations are dependent and not independent because it deals with growth of plants.

I was thinking of using either a multinomial or negative multinomial, however I don't have the experience to decide or to choose which model fits best. Are the above distributions correct for this situation?

Comment: I've [edit]ed your question title to be more specific to the content of the question. Please feel free to revise, but we do want questions to have titles that summarize the body.